# AutoIT store an already open IE window into an object

Tags: internet-explorer, autoit

I am trying to use use the _Navigate command to change the webpage. The issue is that The window will already be open and the only way I can see to use Navigate is to create the window yourself with Create.

Is there a way to somehow store an already opened IE window into an object and then use Navigate on that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `_IEAttach` function.

From the [docs](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_IEAttach.htm)...

Attach to the specified instance of Internet Explorer where the search string sub-string matches (based on the selected mode)

```
#include <IE.au3>
_IEAttach ( $sString [, $sMode = "title" [, $iInstance = 1]] )
```

**Parameters**

```
$sString      String to search for (for "embedded" or "dialogbox", use Title sub-string or HWND of window) 
$sMode        [optional] specifies search mode
                 "title" = (Default) sub-string of main document title
                 "windowtitle" = sub-string of full window title (instead of document title)
                 "url" = sub-string or url of the current page
                 "text" = sub-string in text from the body of the current page
                 "html" = sub-string in html from the body of the current page
                 "hwnd" = hwnd of the browser window
                 "embedded" = title sub-string or hwnd of the window embedding the control
                 "dialogbox" = title sub-string or hwnd of modal/modeless dialogbox
                 "instance" = $sString is ignored, one browser reference returned (by matching instance number) from all available browser instances 
$iInstance    [optional] 1-based index into group of browsers or embedded browsers matching $sString and $sMode. See Remarks.
```

**Return Value**

```
Success:   an object variable pointing to the InternetExplorer Object for all but Embedded and DislogBox modes which return a Window Object. 
Failure:   sets the @error flag to non-zero. 
@error:    5 ($_IEStatus_InvalidValue) - Invalid Value
           7 ($_IEStatus_NoMatch) - No Match 
@extended: Contains invalid parameter number
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I guess I just misunderstood the docs before. Thanks!

Comment: That was a mistake on my part. I checked back in on this post and I thought I didn't select it as correct, so I clicked it again. I have since corrected the mistake. Hope all is well, thanks again for the help!